# How to test Site.com?

Tags: setup, site.com

I've set up a **Site.com** site in my **developer edition** and it looks really good, 
in the production I know we can map the domains and test the url with site.com licence , but to put up a POC, can we somehow map the **Site.com** site to a domain and show how it actually looks like?

or am I missing something?

Comment: Shiv - could you mark Joe Morse's answer as 'correct' - Mitch Hunt's is ranked '-1' and you yourself acknowledge it as incorrect. Moving the green tick to the other answer is the right think to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shiv - Have you checked out Site.com's Anonymous Preview function? That generates a URL that you can share with others outside of Site.com so they can preview your site.

Site.com provides two types of preview: regular page preview, and anonymous preview. You get to anonymous preview in the studio, on the upper right hand side.

Here's the help topic on it:
https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_preview.htm

No need to map a domain name if all you want to do is share with a few others.

Answer (score -2):

Hi unfortunately you cannot do this in a developer edition. Most likely due to licensing concerns.

"You can mask your default site URL with your custom domain name. Simply create a CNAME alias via your 3rd party domain name registrar and point your custom domain name to your Force.com domain name and populate the Custom Web Address field with your custom domain name. **You cannot do this for Developer Edition environments or Developer Sandboxes.** "

From http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites

You should however be able to see the site using the standard domain which will be in a format like **http:// MyDomainName-developer-edition.na6.force.com/** you can find yours at **Setup - Develop - Sites**

Comment: I think that's only for Force.com sites that we can setup standard URLs and not for site.com sites ..

Comment: Answer does not apply to Site.com.